# Azure Automation Test pane without Output stream

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

I realize that if my Powershell runs in Test pane mode without output stream (e.g. **Write-Output**) the runbook will soon complete (after the last **Write-Output**). Has anyone encountered the similar issue or if this is by default, could you please explain?

Comment: can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I'd like to know if Write-Output would be required to be used with Test pane mode in my runbook.

Comment: If you need to log something from your workflow , then you can use it